# Websocket fails to connect on localhost in all browsers

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, websocket

The following code only connects when the server is non-localhost

In Chrome:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:9000');
```

In Chome Console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:9000/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
```

I have a websocket server running at localhost:9000.

However, there is no such issue when I connect to another websocket server on a different machine.

The OS I am using is Mac OS X yosemite and autobahn for server

The server script:

```
import asyncio
import sys
import os
import getopt
from autobahn.asyncio.websocket import WebSocketServerFactory

from server_handler import ServerHandler

def main(argv):
    port = ''
    ip_addr = ''

    try:
      opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"p:a:",["--port=","--address="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
      print('WSServer.py -p <port> -a <address>')

    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-p':
            port = arg
        elif opt == '-a':
            ip_addr = arg

    factory = WebSocketServerFactory()
    factory.protocol = ServerHandler
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    print(str(ip_addr)+','+str(port))    
    coro = loop.create_server(factory, ip_addr, port)
    server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

    try:
        print('server is running')
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        server.close()
        loop.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

server_handler.py

```
from autobahn.asyncio.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol

class ServerHandler(WebSocketServerProtocol):
    def onOpen(self):
        pass
    def onConnect(self):
        pass
    def onMessage(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Seems like the websocket server is not configured correctly, maybe?

Comment: @Zorgatone, I am using the same server script on both my mac and remote server. with the only difference in ip. one is 'localhost' and another is the 'domain'

Comment: Did you try "127.0.0.1" instead of localhost?

Comment: @Zorgatone, yep I have tried both

Comment: Dunno then, sorry. Maybe add more information, and the script code?

Comment: @Zorgatone, yep I have added the scripts related

Comment: @Zorgatone, ok I have found the issue. apparently one of the python package for autobahn server was an incompatible version

Comment: @Mox you should make that an answer :)